# use an existing array, iterate with a vector in a headerfile

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to iterate in an existing array with a vector.

In the class test is a sharedpointer with the name inventory[50]. I would like to iterate within this array with a vector, but while trying, I get the error message from the compiler: no match for 'operator[]' How can I access the elements, which are in the array inventory[50]? Sorry for asking simple questions - I am new to c++.

```
template<typename T>
class Test{
    template<typename m>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Test<m>& test);

protected:   
    std::shared_ptr<Object> inventory[50];
public:
    int addInventory(std::shared_ptr<Object> object);
```

In the .cpp file.:

```
template<typename T>
int Test<T>::addInventory(std::shared_ptr<Object> object) {
     int n = sizeof(inventory) /sizeof(int);
     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> vec1(inventory, inventory + n); 
     for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>::iterator i = vec1.begin(); i != vec1.end(); i++) {
         if(!this->inventory[*i]) { //not working :(
              this->inventory[*i] = object;
              return *i;
         }
     }
}
```

Best regards,

Keita

Comment: Just a suggestion: Get this to work without all the `template ...` stuff in order to not increase the complexity even further.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector` to begin with in the class?

Comment: When discussing C++ it is important to keep the terms "vector" and "pointer" clearly separate. Please [edit] to review and make sure that you use them appropriatly.

Comment: When you derefernece `i` in the loop, you have a value of the type `std::shared_ptr<Object>`. How would this be used as an index into your array?

Comment: `vec1` is completely unrelated to the array. It contains copies of the array's elements.

Comment: Off topic but... why do you have `int n = sizeof(inventory) /sizeof(int);`?  Why `int` when each element of `inventory` is of type `std::shared_ptr<Object>`?

Comment: You do not have a `shared_ptr` with the name `inventory[50]`, you have an array named `inventory`, which contains 50 `shared_ptr`s. (I think you're getting ahead of yourself with all this templating and iterating and `shared_ptr`ing, and need to go back and review the fundamentals.)